# What does "end-of-file" mean in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn C, and am having difficulty understanding what end-of-file means, in terms of a statement like "if fgets() attempts to read past the end of file".
I understand that one can mark an EOF by pressing certain key combos, and that char '\0' represents an EOF, but there must be something basic that I'm not understanding regarding my question, and I hope someone can help explain it to me>

Comment: changed your question tag from `c#` to `c`

Comment: Is this question about `EOF` in C and C-based languages?  Or is this question about the meaning of the English phrase "end of file" which frequently occurs in programming text books?

Comment: It means exactly what it says. You've reached the end of the file. There are no more bytes to read. It literally means "You've reached the end of the file".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file

Answer (score 2):

A file is a finite sequence of bytes, just like a book is a finite sequence of words.  Eventually you reach the end and there's nothing more to read.

A null character does *not* represent the end of a file, by the way — you're probably confusing that with the null character used to mark the end of a string in memory in C/C++.  That's unrelated to files.

Comment: Is `\0` used to mark the end of `C++ string` variables?  Or just char array strings?

Comment: A C++ `std::string` doesn't have to store a a null character at the end of its internal array, but you can call `.c_str()` on it to get a pointer that *is* guaranteed to be null-terminated.